# Why capturing stage doesn't get interrupted with event.stopPropagation?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, stoppropagation, event-propagation

If you run this code and click on P, the whole capturing stage is executed but the bubbling stage is stopped as expected on `div`. What's the issue with this code?

```js
  for(let elem of document.querySelectorAll('*')) {
    elem.addEventListener("click", e => alert(`Capturing: ${elem.tagName}`), true);
    elem.addEventListener("click", e => alert(`Bubbling: ${elem.tagName}`));
  }
```

```html
<form>FORM
  <div onclick="event.stopPropagation()">DIV
    <p>P</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try `stopImmediatePropagation`?

Comment: Just tried, same problem @Bergi

Comment: I believe `event.stopPropagation()` is effective to bubbling phase not capture phase.

Comment: @zer00ne `stopPropagation()` may be used to stop event propagation for events registered in the capturing phase or the bubbling phase. However, during the capturing phase, the first handler processed is the one attached to the outermost parent element (often `<html>`) so it produces a different outcome than stopping event propagation for events registered in the default bubbling phase.

Answer (score 4):

The capturing phase does not get interrupted because in modern browsers events are registered by default in the bubbling phase (so the `onclick()` event in your `<div>` element does not interact with the separate event handler you registered in the capturing phase).

I am not aware of a way to register a capturing phase event handler via an html attribute (other than in certain older browsers where events were registered by default in the capturing phase).

See the snippet below for a modified version of your code that I think is probably what you originally intended. You will see that this code calls `stopPropagation()` inside both the capturing phase and bubbling phase handlers (and results in the expected outcome in both cases).

```js
for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll('*')) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (elem.tagName === 'DIV') {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
    
    console.log(`Capturing: ${elem.tagName}`);
  }, true);
  
  elem.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (elem.tagName === 'DIV') {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
    
    console.log(`Bubbling: ${elem.tagName}`);
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  form
  <div>
    div (click here)
    <p>p</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

In the capturing phase, the browser processes the handlers starting with the outermost parent, so it does not encounter `stopPropagation()` until it has already processed the `click` handlers for all the parent elements `<html>`, `<body>`, etc.

In the bubbling phase, it processes the event handlers starting with the clicked element moving outward through the parent elements.